# Is my question about synthesising controllers for non-minimal-phase systems using Bode plots clear? Why has it not attracted attention?

Tags: discussion

I am talking about this question: [Can the graphoanalytic method of synthesizing controllers by Bode plots (by lead and lag elements) be used for non-minimal-phase systems? If not, why?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/689533/355529)

Do you think it is clear enough? If not, how can I make it more clear?

Comment: Sometimes questions are about a specific area or topic such that they are only answerable by a smaller percentage of users, who may only be active periodically.